# Package protected conditions in Java?

Tags: java

I am a little bit confused. Suppose I have a method

`void test(){ }`

How exactly can I make this **package**-protected? The protected modified makes it overridable by children.

Comment: Do you mean package private?  If so, you already did.  If not, you can't.

Comment: It already is! No `private`, no `public` and no `protected` makes it package-protected (aka default) access.

Comment: Hi, please refer to the following article for more explanation about access modifier. Method or class without access modifier means it has default access modifier.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/access-modifiers-java/

Answer (score 1):

If you declare it as

```
void test(){ }
```

It means this function is package-private. Other classes can use it if they are in the same package.